# Unable to resolve signature of Typescript decorator when imported from another file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following:

**decorator.ts**

```
export function logStuff(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    return {
        value: function (...args: any[]) {
            args.push("Another argument pushed");
            descriptor.value.apply(target, args);
        }
    };
}
```

**Shell.ts**

```
// Removed other imports for brevity
import logStuff = require("utils/log-decorator");

class Shell extends AnotherClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.fooMethod("arg1");
    }

    @logStuff
    private fooMethod(arg1: string, arg2?: string) {
        console.log(`Arguments from original function: ${JSON.stringify(arguments)}`);
    }
}

export = Shell;
```

I get this message (shortened the file path for brevity):

> Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an
>   expression.   Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type 'typeof
>   "/utils/log-decorator"' has
>   no compatible call signatures

However, if I move the function to the top of Shell.ts, it compiles without errors. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `logStuff` is available as an exported member of the module. So you have to access it like:

```
import logStuffModule = require("utils/log-decorator");
//...
@logStuffModule.logStuff
private fooMethod(arg1: string, arg2?: string) { ... }
```

---

Or use ES6-style imports:

```
import { logStuff }  from "utils/log-decorator";

// ...
@logStuff
private fooMethod(arg1: string, arg2?: string) { ... }
```

---

Or you can modify your module by setting the export object as your function and use it like how you are using it now:

```
// decorator.ts
export = function logStuff() {}

// Shell.ts    
import logStuff = require("utils/log-decorator");

// ...
@logStuff
private fooMethod(arg1: string, arg2?: string) { ... }
```